# Error log for MySQL auto import?

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, etl

I have upgraded to the latest version of MySQL Workbench and I am using the autoimport tools for a CSV file I want to work with. There's quite a few fields and some fields may or may not contain valid data. I run the import while changing very few selections along the way. The process will run and it will tell me that it loaded 870 of 980 rows. It doesn't provide any more info as to why the other 110 records were not loaded. Are there any log files or any way for me to debug this and find why records were rejected?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench logs various informations in its wb.log file (which is rotated on each app start). See the help menu "Show Log File".